# Color cells in a grid programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, grid

I am working on an Iphone application. I want to have a grid of small invisible squares.

And I want to be able to change the color of those squares from code.

How can I do that?

Additional information:

The grid is static (some sort of a chess grid) and I need to be able to change the color of a given square in it. For example Change color of square C3 to red and E7 to green.

I don't want to put any content in the squares other than coloring them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass UIView, add some data structure to hold cells info and override [drawRect:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCDGJHF) method.

Something like this:

```
// in view

-(void)drawCellAtRow:(int)row column:(int)column 
{
     // draw a cell          
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // determine which cells have to be drawn for this rect
    // and draw them
}
-(void)changeCellAtRow:(int)row column:(int)column 
{
    // change cell info
    // calculate rect to update
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:dirtyRect];
}

// in view controller   
-(void)eventHandler
{
   [cellView changeCellAtRow:row column:column];
}
```

[Drawing guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

`theView.backgroundColor = color;`

Comment: Thanks but I need at least 100X100 small squares so I'm not sure it is a good idea to have 10000 view.

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to create a view, with 42 subviews (in grid) - I simply used drawRect and drawed necessary color gradients in right positions, And on them - drawed necessary text.
(I also needed different squares in different gradient colors, and if You need also - I am sure You will be able to tweak this code further :) )

```
- (void)drawRect
{
    int mWidth = 99;

    int mHeight = 99;

    //--- now we draw all gradients (will have 1 pix wide space between each)
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {

            //--- gradient color
            CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

            CGFloat colors [] = {  //these values are for a white square block.
                    255/255.0, 255/255.0, 255/255.0, 1.0,
                    255/255.0, 255/255.0, 255/255.0, 1.0
                };

            CGGradient gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);

            CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;


            CGContextSaveGState(context);

            CGContextAddRect(context, rect);

            CGContextClip(context);

            CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(1+j*(mWidth+1),0+i*(mHeight+1),mWidth,mHeight+i*mHeight+i*1));

            CGContextClip(context);


             //+ 1 values to make sure we have one pix wide space between any two squares
            CGContextDrawLinearGradient (context, gradient, CGPointMake(1+j*(mWidth+1), 0+i*(mHeight+1)), CGPointMake(1+j*(mWidth+1),0+mHeight+i*mHeight+i*1), 0);

            CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;

            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
            //===

            //Here We can draw any string labels we need.
        }
    }
```

Good luck!